# How to pass a function as argument for a class constructor in c++

Tags: algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I'm trying to implement an ordered multi map.
But I need to give a function to compare whatever the multimap contain.

Ex:

```
bool compare(string a, string b) { return a<b; }
bool compare2(string a, string b) { return a.size()<b.size(); }


class MultiMap
{
 private:
    toCompare( string a, string b); 

 public:
    MultiMap(function) { toCompare = function };


}
```

So I would like to make set the order in the multimap by a given function.

Is there a way, maybe some a pointer to a function.
Hope you understand what I want to do, if not feel free to ask.

Also, notice this is not the real code, is just something I've writen to give an idea.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: The signature of toCompare needs to match the function that you pass and the declaration of the constructor.

Comment: Containers are often implemented as templates, then you may pass your compare function as template type. This might be the most optimal way to acomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `std::function`, example:

```
class MultiMap
{
 private:
    std::function<bool(string,string)> toCompare;

 public:
    MultiMap(std::function<bool(string,string)> function) : toCompare(std::move(function)) {}

    bool compare(string a, string b) {
        return toCompare(a,b);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 MultiMap mm(compare);
 mm.compare("asd", "Da");
}
```

Or with function pointers:

```
// Define function type
using compare_func = bool(string,string);

class MultiMap
{
 private:
    compare_func* toCompare;    
 public:
    // Constructor accepts pointer to functiontype
    MultiMap(compare_func* function) : toCompare(function) { }

    bool compare(string a, string b) {
        return toCompare(a,b);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 MultiMap mm(compare);
 mm.compare("asd", "Da");
}
```

Comment: Why assign instead of initialize?

Comment: Why copy instead of move?  ;)

Comment: I have added std::move(, I suppose the ultimate version will use forwarding :)

Comment: Naw, forwarding is overkill here.  It would only matter if you had a tiny, yet very expensive to move, function object within the `std::function`.